# How to add a logo image to a rmarkdown pdf in A Shiny app

Tags: r, pdf, shiny, r-markdown

I think that I have a path issue to point a rmarkdown file generating a pdf to a logo image, which needs to be placed in the left corner of the header. I am attempting to place it there with fancyhead. Any help please… many thanks.

The pdf is generated through a call to the downloadButton/downloadHandler combo.

I can get the pdf to print outside of a Shiny context, but it hits an error within Shiny. For info, my actual app is modularised, though the same happens in the example below.

! Package pdftex.def Error: File `rsz_logo_pdf.png' not found: using draft setting.

The project architecture is all on the same level.

```
-- .Rproj.user
-- pdf_logo.Rproj
-- app.R
-- report_logo_dev.Rmd
-- rsz_logo_pdf.png
```

app.R

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  downloadButton("portfolio_report", "pdf", style = "width:100%;")

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$portfolio_report <- downloadHandler(

    filename = "report_logo_dev.pdf",

    content = function(file) {

      tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "report_logo_dev.Rmd")

      file.copy("report_logo_dev.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)

      rmarkdown::render(
        tempReport
        , output_file = file
        , params      = params
        , envir       = new.env(parent = globalenv())
      )
    }
  )


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

report_logo_dev.Rmd

```
---
title: "Report"
output: pdf_document
always_allow_html: true
header-includes:
- \usepackage{makecell, tabularx, float, multirow}
- \usepackage{booktabs}
- \usepackage{fancyhdr}
- \usepackage{lipsum}
- \pagestyle{fancy}
- \fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{rsz_logo_pdf.png}}
- \fancyhead[C]{my pdf title}
- \fancyfoot[L]{\today}
- \fancypagestyle{plain}{\pagestyle{fancy}}
---
```

Comment: You’re copying your rmd to a temp folder and rendering from there. You need to also copy the image to that folder.

Comment: Hi. I’m not sure how to do that, I have had several attempts. Any chance of a quick example please?

Comment: Ah. I got it thanks.